# Caffe only training on one iteration and fails when about to create snaphot

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

i am failing to train [PixelNet](https://github.com/aayushbansal/PixelNet) when caffe creates the network and do one iteration giving the following error

```
I0614 15:02:35.431906 16468 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 0, loss = 3.01473
I0614 15:02:35.431951 16468 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 0.001
F0614 15:02:36.579319 16468 io.cpp:69] Check failed: proto.SerializeToOstream(&output)
```

In [this issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/248) they have discussed about how snapshots and solverstates use  relative paths while saving states files,i have another model that runs fine when i am using  full paths.
I used the full path of the snapshot folder but it continues to give the same error.
I gave full permissions(777) on all folders where the model is located,still get the same error.
I have also enough space on my disk.
I tried to remove the snapshot(prefix,snapshot) related tags in my solver file,still gives me the same error.

Here is the code of my solver:

```
train_net: "/fullpath/PixelNet/models/analysis/lin_bn/semantic_seg/train.prototxt"
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
momentum: 0.9
snapshot: 0
snapshot_prefix: "lin_bn"# used the full path also with no success
weight_decay: 0.0005
random_seed: 1989
```

Comment: what format are you trying to save `binaryproto` or `hdf5`? what is your solver type? (I think there used to be an issue saving hdf5 format of `"Adam"` solverstate...).

Comment: @Shai it is not specified in the solver file, to which i would assume it will fall on SGD

Comment: i just load the solver using "solver=caffe.get_solver(solverpath)"

Comment: @Shai i am not sure which format it is using,but i presume it might be binaryproto since the error code comes from binaryproto checks https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/util/io.cpp#L69

Comment: are you sure you are using the caffe version shipped with PixelNet? is it possible that accidentally you have a different version of caffe running?

Comment: @Shai,i `ve made a very basic mistake, i am sorry for the trouble, #solver.net.save(options['NET_FILE_PATH']+"pixel_net"+str(epoch)+".caffemodel"),i forgot to create NET_FILE_PATH on disk i was saving on each iteration therefore it was failing at each iteration.